# how to search the array with no empty value from mongodb in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, search

I would like to get the data tags from mongodb whose data is not null
"tags" : [ ]

I tried doing $ne but no chance.

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("tags", new BasicDBObject("$ne", []));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using this query
    searchQuery.put("tags.1", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));

Comment: Actually it should be `searchQuery.put("tags.0", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));`