# spring mongodb - How to provide match condition to check for empty array using spring data mongodb api?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

how to perform below operation (it is the actual mongo query) using MatchOperation in Spring data mongodb ?

`$match: { "docs": { $ne: [] } }`

here docs is an array field and want to check that it is not empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to search the array with no empty value from mongodb in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099824/how-to-search-the-array-with-no-empty-value-from-mongodb-in-java)

Comment: I want to perfrom this using spring data's query criteria, not direclty on BasicDBObject

Comment: Here you go `Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(  Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("docs").exists(true)));`

Comment: it checks for the presence of the field (which in this case do exists) not the value of the field which is empty

Comment: Something like `Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("docs").ne(Collections.EMPTY_LIST)));
`

Comment: Criteria.where("docs").not().size(0);

Comment: Thanks Veeram, that worked.

Comment: I tried both options Criteria.where("docs").not().size(0)   &   Criteria.where("docs").ne(Collections.EMPTY_LIST) . but its not working, however if I use the same query generated on console, then I can see proper data, strange!!
@Rakesh can you plz tell which one you implemented

Comment: it is too late but I did end up using `Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("docs").ne(Collections.EMPTY_LIST)));`

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, but I solved is as below.

MatchOperation mathOpertaion = match(Criteria.where("docs")
.elemMatch(new Criteria().exists(true)));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .not

Criteria.where("arr").not().size(0)